# React JS - promise returns before execution completes. Async function does not work

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, return-value, es6-promise

I am trying to load data from firebase by calling a function in which it filters data and returns them.

When I call this function in my main function, it returns "undefined". I know the data is there (console.log(postsArray)) prints the data but I guess the return executes before data is loaded. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
calling_Function_in_Main = async () => {
    const data = await FirebaseData ();
    console.log(data);
  };
```

FirebaseData is the function that I call in my main function to load data and to return them

```
let postsArrays=[];


const FirebaseData = async () => {

  const getViewableLink = async (link) => { //some function  };

  const loadData = async () => {

    const database = firebase.database();
    const data = database.ref();
    const loadProfile = data
      .child('Posts')
      .orderByChild('Active')
      .equalTo(true)
      .once('value', function gotData(data) {

        Object.values(readInfo).forEach(async (element) => {
         element.Option1Link = await getViewableLink(
              preLink + element.Option1Link,
            );
            postsArray.push(element);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      })
      .then((postsArray) => {
          console.log(postsArray);
          return postsArray;
      });
  };

  await loadData();
};
export default FirebaseSwipeData;
```

Comment: try and do `return loadProfile` at then end of your `loadData` function, otherwise your returning nothing  (undefined)..  Also you could get rid of the `async` if your returning a promise.

Comment: Actually your not even using `loadProfile`, you could just do `return data.child('.....`   Also your `forEach(` will want refactoring, because that won't wait either.

Comment: forEach expects a synchronous function, use for loop instead, forEach won’t work with asynchronous code

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `foreach` with async/await because It is not asynchronous. It is blocking.

you have 2 ways to fix this:

## 1- Reading in sequence: you can use `for...of` loop

```js
for(const element of Object.values(readInfo)) {
   element.Option1Link = await getViewableLink(
      preLink + element.Option1Link,
   );
   postsArray.push(element);
}
```

## 2- Reading in parallel: you can use `Promise.all`

```
await Promise.all(Object.values(readInfo).map(async (element) => {
  element.Option1Link = await getViewableLink(
     preLink + element.Option1Link,
  );
  postsArray.push(element);
}));
```

Hope that solves the problem, for you

Comment: Thanks for the help @Hani-Ghazi .Now I get the correct array in `FirebaseData ()` however the data I get in the `calling_Function_in_Main` is still undefined. Am I doing something wrong in returning the `postArray`?

Comment: @Ashton ya you should return the postArray after the `await loadData();`, I also highly recommend to define the `postArray` inside the `FirebaseData` function and before you define `loadData` so you use a fresh variable each time call `FirebaseData` fucntion